# How to format Time Stored in DB2 as hhmmss

Tags: sql, db2

I have time Stored in Db2 Field as hhmmss(41634) . I want to format this in SQL to HH:MM:SS. I have tried many thing like substr 
for ex:

```
   select substr(fieldTME,1,1) as HOUR, substr(fieldTME,2,2) as Minute,
substr(fieldTME,4,2) as Second from tbl1 where filed2 ='80404454'
```

with the above sql iam able to get 4 as hour 16 as minute  34 as seconds . But if the time is value is stored as (102333).The above sql does not work. Can i format the hour,minute and second in SQL as hh:mms:ss

Comment: Is the time field a string or an integer?

Comment: Time values should always be stored as the `Time` datatype (or potentially with a date as a `Timestamp`).  Also, display formatting should usually be left to the _view_ code, not the database - in a web context, the database isn't usually aware of where the requester is from, so it's not able to make the proper decision anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it should be noted that `Date` and `Time` values should always be stored as those types (and together as `Timestamp`, **not** as individual fields), not as `int` or `char` types - the headaches you run into just aren't worth it (mostly relating to invalid values).

Because @galador's answer won't work on my version (iSeries V6R1), here's one that does work (character or numeric types).

```
SELECT TIME(SUBSTR(RIGHT('0' || fieldTME, 6), 1, 2) || ':' ||
            SUBSTR(RIGHT(fieldTME, 4), 1, 2) || ':' ||
            RIGHT(fieldTME, 2)) AS resultTime  
FROM Tbl1
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to normalize the data a bit so that you always have 6 digits.  You can use [`LPAD()`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053529.html) to do this (it will left-pad the column with a string character up to length *x* 
), and then extract the values using `SUBSTR()` as you're doing now:

```
SELECT  SUBSTR(LPAD(fieldTME, 6, '0'), 1, 2)
        || ':' ||
        SUBSTR(LPAD(fieldTME, 6, '0'), 3, 2)
        || ':' ||
        SUBSTR(LPAD(fieldTME, 6, '0'), 5, 2) 
FROM tbl1
WHERE field2 = '80404454'
```

If you actually want to convert to a `TIME` datatype, you can use the `TIME()` function:

```
SELECT  TIME(SUBSTR(LPAD(fieldTME, 6, '0'), 1, 2)
            || ':' ||
            SUBSTR(LPAD(fieldTME, 6, '0'), 3, 2)
            || ':' ||
            SUBSTR(LPAD(fieldTME, 6, '0'), 5, 2) 
        ) AS time
FROM tbl1
WHERE field2 = '80404454'
```

Comment: At least for iSeries V6R1, `LPAD()` doesn't exist, and supplying `':'` would convert properly anyways...

Comment: @X-Zero:  Ah, the joys of DB2 on several platforms.  I usually try to remember to mention that my answers are for Linux/Unix/Windows (and occasionally z/OS), but forgot this time.  (For what it's worth, my answers produce the correct results on LUW and z/OS)